# What Sorting Algorithm I am Using in this Code?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Hello guys I was learning about sorting algorithm of bubble-sort and after reading the algorithm , I made this code. But funny it is I don't find similarity with the actual code of bubble-sort. So please tell me which sorting algorithm I am using?

```
public class Sort {

    void sortfun() {
        int[] a= {14,33,27,35,10};
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++) {
                if(a[i]>a[j]) {
                    int temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i : a) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sort bs=new Sort();
    bs.sortfun();

 }

}
```

Comment: Never seen a question here of "Guess what I was trying to do", it is usually other way around :)

Comment: You have written a less elegant bubble-sort implementation.

Comment: Well, it actually is quite often "Guess what I was trying to do", it just is not said out loud normally.

Comment: Well that here is not the actual BubbleSort just a very close implementation of it

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Selection Sort` because you are looking for smallest element and replacing it with position `i`.

Comment: Not at all, he is just swapping i and i+n if i+n is smaller

Comment: Actually this is sort of true. Position `i` counts as the pivot position and `j` looks for the smallest possible element it can put there. It's sort of true because there's more swapping done than most implementations out there

Answer (score 1):

I think that is `SelectionSort`. 
 It's very similar to it, at least. 
Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article about asking questions on this website, since I'm not sure that you read it and know how you should ask them. 
Also for some sorting and algorithms in general I would suggest you to check next sources:

- [Geeks for Geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)
- [CLRS](http://is.ptithcm.edu.vn/~tdhuy/Programming/Introduction.to.Algorithms.pdf)
- [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for void sortfun()

```
 {
    int[] a= {14,33,27,35,10};

      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
            if(a[i]>a[j]) {
                int temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
```